# Django signal gets triggered before file is saved in server?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-signals

I am learning how to work with Django signals and celery tasks. So, I am uploading a bulk csv file to the server and my goal is to read the contents of the file once it is uploaded. Now, this is the approach I used, once the Fileupload object is saved, I am triggering the django post_save signal which basically does some validation and then triggers the celery task (which is where all the file read operations are done). Problem is that file is empty when it gets uploaded to the server. I noticed by commenting out the django signal bit and the file gets uploaded with the proper contents but once I activate the signal, it somehow interrupting with the file upload operation. How can i activate the django signal when the file is completely uploaded with the contents.

```
class FileUpload(models.Model):

    file = models.FileField(blank=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(FileType, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(FileCategory, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default=STATUS_NEW)

def upload_file(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        process_upload_file.delay(instance.id)

@app.task(ignore_result=True)
def process_upload_file(file_id):
    try:
        logger.debug('Files:process_upload_file - called.')
        try:
            upload_file = FileUpload.objects.get(id=int(file_id))
        except FileUpload.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        if not upload_file:
            logger.error('Files:process_upload_file - Could not locate upload file with ID={}'.format(file_id))
            return
        elif not upload_file.type:
            logger.debug('Files:process_upload_file - identify.')
        elif upload_file.status == FileUpload.STATUS_NEW:
            print('Files:process_upload_file - started.')
            extract_file_tag(file_id)
    except:
        logger.exception('Files:process_upload_file - failed.')

def extract_file_tag(file_id):
    file_data = FileUpload.objects.get(id=file_id)
    file_name = str(file_data.file)
    print('filename',file_name)
    print('file_data',file_data.file)
    file_to_read = file_data.file
    with open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + file_name, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in file_to_read.chunks():
            print('chunk',chunk)


post_save.connect(upload_file,sender=FileUpload)

views.py
    def post(self,request):

        file_type,type_exists = FileType.objects.get_or_create(name='BulkSchoolUpload')
        file_category,category_exists = FileCategory.objects.get_or_create(name='school')
        user,user_exists = User.objects.get_or_create(username='system')
        print('file_type',file_type)
        print('file_category',file_category)
        file = request.FILES['file']
        print('file',file)
        comment = request.POST.get('comments',None)
        name = request.POST.get('filename',None)


        file_upload = FileUpload(file=file,type=file_type,category=file_category,status=FileUpload.STATUS_NEW,comments=comment,progress=100,
                                 creator=user)
        file_upload.save()
```

Comment: Can you share the view that takes the uploaded file and creates the `FileUpload` object?

Comment: @IainShelvington:- I have added

Comment: There is an error in the line that connects the signal, it should be `post_save.connect(upload_file,sender=FileUpload)`

Comment: Which line exactly is having the issue? I assume in the extract_file_tag function?

Comment: @IainShelvington:- Yeah i corrected that error. The thing is in the extract_file_tag function, when i try to read the contents of the uploaded file, it returns empty and when i check the uploaded file, it has empty contents.And this happens when i am using the signals.

Comment: @IainShelvington:- Somehow, my file is saved but no data is appended to the file and the uploaded file is always empty

Comment: You need to change the flags passed to open 'wb+' means "write/binary and truncate the file". You should use 'r' for reading text and 'rb' for reading binary data

Comment: @IainShelvington:- I see that was my mistake. I was not passing the right flag